# Dynamic content with URL in email signature

Tags: javascript, html, email

I'm trying to put dynamic content with URL into my email signature.
I wanted to do somethink like this:
***check out the newest post [on my blog](http://google.com)***

I tried to do something with JS and document.write in file on my server but it don't work. What I should do to do this?

Comment: Note that the [tag:signature] is not correct as that's about *method* signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript won't be of any help here, AFAIK no email clients has ever supported Javascript in email (and is likely to).

You can have a static link `http://yourblog.com/newest/`, redirecting automatically to your latest post. If you want your signature to be updated with the post title, you can add a `<img>` referencing to a server-generated image containing the title of your post.

Comment: Awesome answer covering the options.